# Python While Loop for Products of Powers of 2

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop, product

I need help creating a function that uses a while loop in order to find the products of powers of 2.

Here's the question:

> Create a Python function called `productOfPowersOf2` which takes two
>   arguments, both of which are non-negative integers. For purposes of
>   this problem, let's call the first argument `exp1` and the second
>   argument `exp2`. Your function should compute and return (not print) the
>   product of all powers of 2 from 2exp1 to 2exp2. Here are some examples
>   of how your function should behave:
>
> ```
> >>> productOfPowersOf2(0,0)
> 1
> >>> productOfPowersOf2(1,1)
> 2
> >>> productOfPowersOf2(1,2)
> 8
> >>> productOfPowersOf2(1,3)
> 64
> ```

what i have written is:

```
def productsOfPowersOf2(exp1,exp2):
    total=0
    num=0
    while num<=exp2:
        total=(2**exp1)*(2**(exp1+num))
        num=num+1
    return(total)
```

but this doesnt work. can anyone help??

Comment: Does it not work because your indentation is incorrect?

Comment: I just indented the return line and when i entered (1,1) it gave me 4 when it should be 2

Comment: Should that be "all powers of `2` from `2**exp1` to `2**exp2`"?

Comment: yes all powers of 2 from 2**exp1 to 2**exp2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the assignment says this?

> Your function should compute and return (not print) the product of all powers of 2 from 2<sup>exp1</sup> to 2<sup>exp2</sup>

1) You aren't taking the cumulative product; you only reassigned `total` to the next value.

```
total=(2**exp1)*(2**(exp1+num))
```

In other words, when the loop exits, you only get this, which is too probably always greater than the value you want, if I had to guess

```
total=(2**exp1)*(2**(exp1+exp2))
```

Hint: You could use math. `x^y * x^z = x ^ (y + z)`. Sum the exponents before you take the power of two.

**SPOILER**

> `def productOfPowersOf2(exp1,exp2):
>       total = 2**exp1
>       exp1 += 1
>       while exp1 <= exp2:
>           total *= 2**exp1
>           exp1 += 1
>       return total`

Comment: yeah the while loop is a must because we are learning to work with while loops, not working around it

Comment: Okay, then you should set `num = exp1` since you need to loop up to `exp2`, not starting from `0`

Comment: after setting 'num=exp1' should i change anything else? Cause i just did that and now '(1,1)' gives me '8'

Comment: Write out your code by hand... on paper. You'll quickly see the issue, I believe.

Comment: should i also change `total=(2**exp1)*(2**(exp1+num))` to `total=(2**(exp1+num)`?

Comment: That is closer, but you still have the `total=` problem. You are only assigning total to the final iteration of the loop

Comment: would it be better to make it `total=total*(2**(exp1+num)`

Comment: it gives me `8` again when i enter `(1,1)` :/

Comment: Should give you `0` if you started `total = 0`

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well:

```
def productOfPowersOf2(a,b): 
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x*y ,[2**i for i in range(a,b+1)])
```

Comment: My only concern is that this does not invole a while loop